# What are the device numbers reported by lsof?

Tags: devices, vino, lsof

What are the device numbers reported by `lsof`?

I read [the man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/lsof.8.html), [Identify devices from lsof](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1179216/identify-devices-from-lsof), and [this](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/admin-guide/devices.txt).

Still I do not know what is its meaning. In particular, for this case, what can I infer from the numbers?

```
$ lsof -ai tcp -c vino-server
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() tracefs file system /sys/kernel/debug/tracing
      Output information may be incomplete.
COMMAND    PID     USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
vino-serv 4011    user1   12u  IPv4   27353      0t0  TCP *:5900 (LISTEN)
vino-serv 4011    user1   11u  IPv6   27352      0t0  TCP *:5900 (LISTEN)
vino-serv 4011    user1   14u  IPv4 7506511      0t0  TCP XXXXXXXXXX (ESTABLISHED)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, each of these is [the inode number of the corresponding socket](https://github.com/lsof-org/lsof/blob/df01ed314cf9e98a62058501684ab54f44c18c42/dialects/linux/dsock.c#L4767). You have listed open TCP sockets, and sockets are identified by their inode number. You can see the same numbers if you do `ls -l /proc/<pid>/fd` or `ls -Lli /proc/<pid>/fd` (in this case, `<pid>` is 4011). You can use the inode number when looking for information about that socket (e.g., in `/proc/net/tcp` or the `ss` command).

Comment: So the output of `ss` (with a suitable flag, whatever that is) would contain `27352`, `27353` and `7506511`?
Haven't seen it with the flags I used so far.

Comment: Ask for extended information with `-e` (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/a/29340794/2072269)